# SQL Developer RAM Consumption issue

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

When I open multiple packages in the sql developer, it is consuming too much ram even after closing the packages, the ram is not freeing up automatically.

To Freeup the RAM I have to restart the sql developer. Is there a way or option in the sql developer to free the RAM utlization ?

Comment: version of SQL Developer? you may want to look at decreasing value for preferences - code editor - parser - parser threshold

Comment: Version 21.4.2.018. I will try the suggested settings, thank you

Comment: you can also try version 23.1 - it's 2 years newer, updated parser, jdbc driver, and java will all help, probably